# Aliases in Cassandra CQL

Tags: select, cassandra, alias, cql, aliases

My question is about using aliases in CQL queries.
For example in SQL we can write:

```
SELECT p.name FROM Persons as p
```

Is there something similar in CQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I browsed through the [documentation](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/references/cql/index#cql-command-reference) of CQL3 I didn't find any reference to using the `as` alias.

I'd advise you to have a read through datastax's documentation on what the [SELECT](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/references/cql/SELECT) statement can and cant do in `CQL 3.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help !  
It seems like Cassandra doesn't support using aliases in queries :/

Comment: @user2090879 Dont forget, CQL is still fairly new and its feature set is growing rapidly! Perhaps you can propose the 'as' alias to be a future feature in the CQL select statement.

Answer (score 8):

From cassandra 2.0, CQL 3 supports aliases in SELECT

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql-in-cassandra-2-0

SELECT event_id, 
                 dateOf(created_at) AS creation_date,
                 blobAsText(content) AS content 
            FROM timeline;